# Push notification not work for both Nougat & Oreo into same time

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat

i have 2 function that's Push Notification.

For Nougat (7.0) (not work higher than 24)

```
  Uri SoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri((RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));


                    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(first.this)
                            .setVibrate(new long[] { 350, 350})
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.testicon)
                            .setContentTitle("test tittle")
                            .setContentText("test content")
                            .setSound(SoundUri).build();

                    NotificationManager notifmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notifmanager.notify(0,notification);
```

---

For Oreo or higher + (8.0) (not work for Nougat api 24)

```
 CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        int notifyID = 1;

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 350, 350})
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.testicon)
                .setContentTitle("test tittle")
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID).build();

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);
```

now i use Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.testttt"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

### is there Push Notification (method / function) that accepted by almost all android version's (so i wanna make it accepted atleast api +17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put check if OS version is Oreo or greater then use channel otherwise do not create channel and set its id on notification. Channel is needed for Oreo and above with notification.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notification.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
}
```